# What DB design pattern it is: main entity has field with actual value and details are in separate table?

Tags: design-patterns, database-design

I have PERSONS entity and I should add ASSIGNED_LEVEL (INT) field to it and keep the history who assigned the level, when assignment was done and what documents were used in the assignment.

My proposed solution is to add ASSIGNED_LEVEL to PERSONS entity and then use after insert/update triggers to fill automatically PERSON_LEVELS table with fields (ID, FK_PERSON, ASSIGNED_LEVLE, USER, TIMESTAMP) and afterwards I can fill PERSON_LEVEL_ARGUMENTS (ID, FK_PERSON_LEVEL, DOC_BLOB) (but that is optionally).

My boss is not so happy about this, he thinks that PERSONS entity should not be littered with new fields and the PERSON_LEVELS solely can do the job without PERSONS.ASSIGNED_LEVEL. But I would like to keep the present/actual value in the PERSONS entity.

So - is there DB design pattern for the solution that I have described and that I prefer? Essentially - that main entity contains the actual value and the history and additional info is kept into separate table that is automatically updated. I would be more relaxed if I knew that my solution is the optimal one.

Comment: You might use a Join statement, order by latest assignment and pick the first to get the current ASSIGNMENT_LEVEL. There's no need for a field in persons table.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you boss's point of view.  A PERSON can exist without an ASSIGNED_LEVEL and so, from a purist perspective, ASSIGNED_LEVEL doesn't belong "in" the PERSON Entity.

However, the *physical* implementation of an Entity (i.e. a Table) *need not* be exactly the same structure as the Entity.  For performance or other reasons, you may choose to model the data *physically* in a different way.  This is where Pragmatism treads firmly on the toes of Modelling Purism.

Moving this data out into a separate table adds to the workload needed to get hold of the current value, which is the one that you'll want the vast majority of the time.   No matter how you model it, going off to another table will be slower than holding one, extra field in the PERSON table.  **Not by much**, to be sure, but it will be slower *and* it will get worse as the table grows in size.

Some possibilities:

- Add an "Effective Date" column to the linked table, indicating when each associated record starts or ends (or both).  This gives you a time-series of changes, of which you'd normally want the most recent.  Careful indexing will help here.
- Add a "current" column to the linked table, to make finding that particular entry faster.  Again, remember to include this in any indexes you put on this table.
- Add a "current" ASSIGNED_LEVEL to the PERSON entity and use the linked table just for the change *history*.